# Equivalent to AO7400A MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, integrated-circuit, replacement

My Dell laptop (Inspiron 15 7559) has a dead AO7400A MOSFET, and I've been looking all over for a replacement, but with no luck. Does anyone know an equivalent to it, or maybe somewhere I would be able to find one?

If I were to find one that is not for my specific laptop model, but a generic AO7400A, what are the chances of it working? Because I assume if it has the same name there probably aren't that many variations of it, or am I wrong to assume that?

Any information about it would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The [AON7400A](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AON7400A.pdf) is an N-channel MOSFET in 8-DFN-EP 3x3 package rated for an absolute maximum of 30V and 40A on the Drain and +-20V on the Gate, 20nC Gate charge at 10V, and < 10.5mΩ resistance with 4.5V Gate drive. Any FET with similar specifications will probably work fine.

Many suppliers have 'parametric' filters that you can select a range of specifications from to narrow down the search for a suitable substitute. Here's an example result from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.co.nz/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?FV=570%7C377049%2C606%7C378999%2C608%7C214397%2C608%7C214398%2C608%7C214399%2C608%7C214401%2C608%7C214402%2C1993%7C208524%2C1993%7C208752%2C1994%7C1945%2Cmu30V%7C2068%2C-8%7C278&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1291&page=2&stock=1&k=mosfet&pageSize=25&pkeyword=mosfet):-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There a few preliminary parameters to match.

The problem with too low RdsOn is the gate charge becomes large and may affect RC time constant with driver to this power FET. If too high then it can get too hot.     If the RdsOn at 2.5V is too high then it may get too hot at 3V.

### AO7400A Product Summary

- \$BVdss=30V~~1.7A ~N Channel ~MOSFET\$
- \$R_{ DS(ON)}~  < 85mΩ ~~ @~ V_{ GS} =2.5V~~~~ \$ ,   **Vgs(th)=1V nom.@ Id =250µA** Gate Threshold Voltage
- \$SC-70~~
  (SOT-323)\$

Sometimes search tools don't use the same voltage for RdsOn so I used 10V even if the application does not.

[image]
The other parameters are of secondary importance usually acceptable if above are matched,

**If these 3 parameters are matched closely, I estimate you have a 95% chance of success.**

- other critical parameters are Ciss, Coss, Crss, Is, Imax, g(fs),

135k in stock $0.44 (1pc)

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-IR/IRLML6344TRPBF?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2FWi5%252BqVgN3%252BWS8eWKdyS0xC9E%3D